# Convert to sentence case in R

Tags: r, case, sentencecase

I am trying to clean below data in R
I have a vector of strings, that looks something like this -

```
    /organization/-fame
    /ORGANIZATION/-QOUNTER
    /organization/-qounter
    /ORGANIZATION/-THE-ONE-OF-THEM-INC-
    /organization/0-6-com
    /ORGANIZATION/004-TECHNOLOGIES
    /organization/01games-technology
    /ORGANIZATION/0NDINE-BIOMEDICAL-INC
    /organization/0ndine-biomedical-inc
    /ORGANIZATION/0XDATA
    /organization/0xdata
    /ORGANIZATION/0XDATA
    /organization/0xdata
    /ORGANIZATION/1
    /organization/1
    /ORGANIZATION/1
    /organization/1-2-3-listo
    /ORGANIZATION/1-4-ALL
    /organization/1-618-technology
    /ORGANIZATION/1-800-DENTIST
    /organization/1-800-doctors
    /ORGANIZATION/1-800-PUBLICRELATIONS-INC-
    /organization/1-mainstream
    /ORGANIZATION/1-OF-99
    /organization/10-20-media
    /ORGANIZATION/10-20-MEDIA
```

I want to change the case of every word in the string to sentence case. So 
after changing it all must look like -

```
    /Organization/-Fame
    /Organization/-Qounter
    /Organization/-The-One-Of-Them-Inc-
    /Organization/0-6-Com
    /Organization/004-Technologies
    /Organization/01Games-Technology
    /Organization/0Ndine-Biomedical-Inc
    /Organization/0Xdata
    /Organization/1
    /Organization/1-2-3-Listo
    /Organization/1-4-All
    /Organization/1-618-Technology
    /Organization/1-800-Dentist
    /Organization/1-800-Doctors
    /Organization/1-800-Publicrelations-Inc-
    /Organization/1-Mainstream
    /Organization/1-Of-99
    /Organization/10-20-Media
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression. With your sample input

```
x<-c("/organization/-fame", "/ORGANIZATION/-QOUNTER", "/organization/-qounter", 
"/ORGANIZATION/-THE-ONE-OF-THEM-INC-", "/organization/0-6-com", 
"/ORGANIZATION/004-TECHNOLOGIES", "/organization/01games-technology", 
"/ORGANIZATION/0NDINE-BIOMEDICAL-INC", "/organization/0ndine-biomedical-inc", 
"/ORGANIZATION/0XDATA", "/organization/0xdata", "/ORGANIZATION/0XDATA", 
"/organization/0xdata", "/ORGANIZATION/1", "/organization/1", 
"/ORGANIZATION/1", "/organization/1-2-3-listo", "/ORGANIZATION/1-4-ALL", 
"/organization/1-618-technology", "/ORGANIZATION/1-800-DENTIST", 
"/organization/1-800-doctors", "/ORGANIZATION/1-800-PUBLICRELATIONS-INC-", 
"/organization/1-mainstream", "/ORGANIZATION/1-OF-99", "/organization/10-20-media", 
"/ORGANIZATION/10-20-MEDIA")
```

You can run

```
gsub("([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]]+)", "\\U\\1\\L\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
```

to get

```
 [1] "/Organization/-Fame"                     
 [2] "/Organization/-Qounter"                  
 [3] "/Organization/-Qounter"                  
 [4] "/Organization/-The-One-Of-Them-Inc-"     
 [5] "/Organization/0-6-Com"                   
 [6] "/Organization/004-Technologies"          
 [7] "/Organization/01Games-Technology"        
 [8] "/Organization/0Ndine-Biomedical-Inc"     
 [9] "/Organization/0Ndine-Biomedical-Inc"     
[10] "/Organization/0Xdata"                    
[11] "/Organization/0Xdata"                    
[12] "/Organization/0Xdata"                    
[13] "/Organization/0Xdata"                    
[14] "/Organization/1"                         
[15] "/Organization/1"                         
[16] "/Organization/1"                         
[17] "/Organization/1-2-3-Listo"               
[18] "/Organization/1-4-All"                   
[19] "/Organization/1-618-Technology"          
[20] "/Organization/1-800-Dentist"             
[21] "/Organization/1-800-Doctors"             
[22] "/Organization/1-800-Publicrelations-Inc-"
[23] "/Organization/1-Mainstream"              
[24] "/Organization/1-Of-99"                   
[25] "/Organization/10-20-Media"               
[26] "/Organization/10-20-Media"
```

Comment: Above code is not giving me answer - it gave me a warning msg, 
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 1, value = c(NA, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

and converted the string into NA. Likewise many strings are converted into NA

Comment: Did you try it with the data I provided? The error sounds like you have a factor vector rather than a character vector and you are attempting to reassign back to that vector. That's not information you included in your original post.

Comment: So will your solution work if i convert the factor vector into character vector ? Let me try that.